# Overloaded std::ostream operator<< not called, stream gets variable address instead of the object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I have a problem when I call `operator<<` on a pointer. I have searched through SO and asked my question on Google, but all proposed solutions did not solve my problem. To illustrate my problem, please see a simplified piece of my code:

**Marker.h**:

```
class Marker {
     ...
public:
     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Marker& marker);
     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Marker* marker);
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Marker& marker) {
      out << "Marker " << marker._name << " of type " << marker._type << " at position " << marker._position;
      return out;
}

 inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Marker* marker) {
      out << *marker;
      return out;
 }
```

**Landmark.h**:

```
 class Landmark {
       ...
       Marker* m_marker;
       ...
 };
```

**Landmark.cpp**:

```
 void Landmark::print( std::ostream& out )
 {
     out << "Marker GENERIC: " << m_marker << std::endl;
     //out << "Marker GENERIC: " << *m_marker << std::endl;
 }
```

This does not link under Visual Studio 2008. I get a load of `unresolved external symbol` errors. If i remove the `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Marker* marker);`, the code compiles, but instead of the expected formatted output, I get only the memory address of the pointer to the marker `Marker* Landmark::m_marker`. Uncommenting the second line turns my code into incompilable.

How should I overload `operator<<` so that I get the correct output?

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: If you try defining `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Marker* marker)` as a (non-inline) function in its own compilation unit (i.e., in a .cpp file), then does that make the linker happy?

Comment: The compiler does not argue then, but the project which includes this DLL would not compile: `unresolved external symbol` on function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Marker* marker)`. Should this function be defined in the global namespace? In my case, all my classes and the overloaded operator function lie inside my namespace.

Comment: @PavloDyban: they *shall* be inside the namespace, this is not the issue.

Comment: Note: for the pointer overload, two things are missing. It should read `Marker const* marker`, as the `Marker` instance is not mutated in any way; and it should test for nullity, just in case, perhaps output `<null>` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace mine {
class Marker {
public:
     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Marker& marker);
     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Marker* marker);
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Marker& marker) {
     out << "Marker";
     return out;
}

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Marker* marker) {
     out << *marker;
     return out;
}
} // namespace mine

int main() {
  mine::Marker marker;
  mine::Marker* m = &marker;

  std::cout << m << "\n";
}
```

And it works [as expected](http://ideone.com/EbN34).

The error you point at is a linker error, it is telling you that the compiler emitted a call to a method for which no function was emitted.

I will suppose that you have lied to us or that Visual Studio is once again wrong.

- if you lied (ie, did not copy the exact code): note that when definining an `inline` method, the whole method body should be included before using it, therefore *Landmark.cpp* should include the methods definitions.
- Alternatively, it may be necessary to help VS out by predeclaring the function before friending them so that VS understands that they do live in the `mine` namespace and not in the global namespace.

Something like:

```
namespace mine {
  class Marker;

  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Marker& marker);
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Marker* marker);

  class Marker {
  public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Marker& marker);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Marker* marker);
  };

  inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Marker& marker) {
    out << "Marker";
    return out;
  }

  inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Marker* marker) {
    out << *marker;
    return out;
  }
} // namespace mine
```

Comment: Thanks for your extensive reply! The second trick with explaining to the compiler that functions are in the local namespace has worked. The problem lay perhaps in that I called operator<< on another object inside operator<<, and the same error occurred twice, so it was harder to track it down.

Comment: @PavloDyban: I have had this bug with VS2003 (if memory serves right) and it had nothing to do with "recursion". Normally the `friend` declaration should introduce the function so declared in the namespace of the class, but it seems that if no prior declaration exist VS stumbles on it. I am not sure whether this is what the Standard specifies or not (and I hope it is a bug).

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you have overloads to take both pointers and references to the object. You're passing a pointer, so the overload that takes the reference won't be used.

You want to reverse that: get rid of the overload that takes a pointer, and use the one that takes a reference. Use it by dereferencing the pointer: `out << *m_marker;`

Comment: Thank you! You gave me a correct advice! Now, if I still wanted to leave the line `out << "Marker GENERIC: " << m_marker << std::endl;`, i.e. by passing the address of my marker object, how should I overload `operator<<`?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Marker* marker);
```

To this

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Marker marker);
```

And then use this

```
out << "Marker GENERIC: " << *m_marker << std::endl;
```

Your output operator was expecting a pointer while you were passing the actual object.

Comment: Depending on how `Marker` is implemented, it may not be a good idea to pass it by value -- probably better to make that second argument to the streaming operator `const Marker& marker` instead of just `Marker marker`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I hid the overload with the pointer as an argument and I used the reference pointer instead. This is almost the same that you proposed by passing the marker by value. However, I wish I did not have an asterisk in the line `out << "Marker GENERIC: " << *m_marker << std::endl;`. How should I overload my operator to take in a pointer to `Marker` and output the contents of the object?